# continuously reading from a file from Hdfs using BufferedReader

Tags: java, hadoop, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read a file from Hdfs using BufferedReader in real time i.e. if the reader reached the end of file, I want to wait for the next entry instead of exiting from the while loop.

```
BufferedReader br = ...
String line = null;
while(true)
{
    line = br.readLine();
    if(line==null)
    {   
        System.out.println("No log...Going to sleep");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        continue;
    }

    System.out.println("We got a line: "+ line);

}
```

Now, when all lines have been consumed, it does go to sleep instead of exiting. But when I append lines to the file, it does not print and keeps on going to sleep. The file to be read is in hdfs and for testing i am appending text like this:

```
echo "Hello World" | hadoop fs -appendToFile - /data/text.txt
```

The append seems to work correctly because when I do a cat (or run the java code again), I can see the added text. 
Also, instead of checking `if(line==null)` I also tried `if(!(br.ready())` still didn't work. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: `ready()` is not a test for end of stream.

Comment: It seems like the problem is related to appending to hdfs. I tried using the `org.apache.commons.io.input.Tailer` to keep track of things appended: this works perfectly when I'm testing it on a file on the local file system but doesn't on hdfs